# Blend two videos with chroma key using GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I try to blend two videos using GPUImage. One of them (show.mov) contain green background.
Here is [show.mov](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9xw9xopati0ezu/snow.mov) and [galaxy.mov](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kntpq1f1cjgt1j9/galaxy.mov).
I downloaded the latest version of `GPUImage` and changed `SimpleVideoFileFilter` example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _movie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"galaxy" ofType:@"mov"]]];
    _greenMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"snow" ofType:@"mov"]]];

    _movie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    _greenMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

    _filter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];

    [_greenMovie addTarget:_filter];
    [_movie addTarget:_filter];

    GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
    [_filter addTarget:filterView];

    [_greenMovie startProcessing];
    [_movie startProcessing];
}
```

When I run the project (no matter on device or simulator) I get just blank white view and after 14 seconds (length of show.mov) I see only last frame of blended videos. Using writer from example create file on disk, but this file can't be opened.
I am using iPhone 5 with 7.0.3 and XCode 5.0.2
Did I miss something?

Comment: This is most likely due to a known bug in the blending of two movie sources: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1249

Comment: Thank you Brad. Do I need to close this question?

Comment: Any idea about this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181582/terminating-app-due-to-memory-gpuimagechromakeyblendfilter-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BradLarson, he pointed to an [github issue](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1221) where I found [commit](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/commit/42a683802cb4bb71f411e2a8d66c12747ca7efc6) that caused this problem.

In `GPUImageMovie.m` I comment two lines in `startProcessing` method:

```
[inputAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler: ^{
    //runSynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue(^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVKeyValueStatus tracksStatus = [inputAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
        if (!tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
        {
            return;
        }
        blockSelf.asset = inputAsset;
        [blockSelf processAsset];
        blockSelf = nil;
    //});
}];
```

Comment: That's interesting. I was actually looking somewhere else. When I get a chance, I'll look into that some more.

Comment: Any idea about this .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181582/terminating-app-due-to-memory-gpuimagechromakeyblendfilter-ios